# $\arccos \sqrt\frac{x+1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}*\arccos x$

Tags: trigonometry

I found an exercize with this equality

$\arccos \sqrt\frac{x+1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}*\arccos x$

Where can I find this formula with the proof possibly?

Comment: Use cos of double angle  of LHS on $ \cos ( 2 \, arccos \sqrt{\frac {x+1}{2}}) = \cos(arccos x) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x=\cos y$, then use
$$
\cos\frac{y}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{\cos y+1}{2}}.
$$
Finally, invert the substitution.

Comment: Actually $$\cos\dfrac y2=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos y}2}$$ right? We need to justify for positive sign

Comment: Yes, you have to add a $\pi$ term. Write $-\cos\frac{y}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{\cos y+1}{2}}$ and then consider that $-\cos\frac{y}{2}=\cos\left(\frac{y}{2}+\pi\right)$. The Op's question implies a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $\arccos x=2t,x=\cos2t$

Using [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $0\le2t\le\pi$

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x}2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos2t}2}=\sqrt{\cos^2t}$$

$=+\cos t$  as $\cos t\ge0$